# PHP regex doesn't working in my website but works on regular expression editor

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-match, spaces

### my aim

for the "author name input", to be sure that only spaces and utf-8 letters are inputted. my website lang is Turkish, Turkish alphabet has non-English characters.

### my weird issue

**this regex works on rubular.com**
if input string : "Selim Çınar" result : matches
if input string : "Selim Çınar 12" result : don't match
regex: **`/^[\p{L} ]+$/u`**

**then I created trial.php on my website and run codes below**

### 1

```
echo '<br /><br /><br />';
    $str ='Selim Cinar';
    if (!preg_match("/^[\p{L} ]+$/u", $str))
    {echo 'no, not only utf-8 letters and spaces';}
    else {$str.' yes utf-8 letters and spaces';}
echo '<br /><br /><br />';
```

**result for code above** : empty page with only `<br />` tags at source page

### 2

```
echo '<br /><br /><br />';
    $str ='Selim Çınar'; //includes Tr characters
    if (!preg_match("/^[\p{L} ]+$/u", $str))
    {echo 'no, not only utf-8 letters and spaces';}
    else {$str.' yes utf-8 letters and spaces';}
echo '<br /><br /><br />';
```

**result for code above** : empty page with only `<br />` tags at source page

### 3

### code source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php

```
    $str ='Selim Çınar'; //includes Tr characters
    $str =trim($str);
    $str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
    setLocale(LC_CTYPE, 'TR_tr.UTF-8');
    if (ctype_alpha($str)) {echo 'yes utf-8 letters';}
    else {echo 'no, not only utf-8 letters';}
```

**result for code above** : no, not only utf-8 letters

### 4

### code source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php

```
    $str ='Selim Cinar';
    $str =trim($str);
    $str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
    setLocale(LC_CTYPE, 'TR_tr.UTF-8');
    if (ctype_alpha($str)) {echo 'yes utf-8 letters';}
    else {echo 'no, not only utf-8 letters';}
```

**result for code above** : yes utf-8 letters

### my phpinfo

PHP Version 5.4.10
Apache 2.0 Handler
Apache API version: 20051115
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.20 2011-10-21

### about trial.php

trial.php is pure php. no html header declaration.

## My Questions

1. why am I getting empty page for case 1 and case 2 **{! UPDATE : SOLVED by MikeM below }**
2. Why case 3 doesn't understand "SelimÇınar" as utf-8? Is my code
   false (`setLocale` part maybe)?

## UPDATE

**question 1 is solved by MikeM.**

**question 2 still exists as an question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `setlocale` or `utf8_decode`, your problem is very simple in that your php source files are not saved in UTF-8. This depends on your text editor.

This is what WILL work when you saved your file correctly:

```
$str = 'Selim Çınar'; //Since this is a string literal, its encoding is determined by
                     //how this source file was saved
if (preg_match("/^[\p{L} ]+$/u", $str)) {
    echo 'yes only utf-8 letters or spaces';
} else {
    echo 'no, not only utf-8 letters or spaces';
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are so sure the OP's source files are not UTF-8. Even as UTF-8, the code for the OP's second question gives `'no, not only utf-8 letters'` and he wants to know why this is.

Comment: @MikeM then even you don't have your source files as UTF-8, it does not print anything for me. That's because there is no `echo` in the else.

Comment: @MikeM hmm, wait, are you referring to the snippet `2.` or the final snippet in the question?

Comment: @MikeM I see, I have nothing on that beacuse it makes no sense to use `ctype_*` functions in the first place. :)

Comment: @Esailija ok, then I understand that if I declare HTML lang is utf-8 then I won't have case 3 and case 4 which correspond to my question 2. Thank you.

Comment: @AndreChenier just don't use anything that depends on `setlocale`, there are always alternatives that just work.

Answer (score 1):

You are only getting an empty page for cases 1 and 2 because the regex successfully matches `$str` and therefore the `else` branch is executed, but there is no `echo` there so nothing is printed.

I don't know the answer to your second question. The `setLocale` looks okay to me, but its behaviour is system dependent.

Comment: thank you Mike. I updated my question. My first question has been solved by you.